# Abbreviation of Strings that Remains Unique

Tags: sql, r, oracle, distinct-values

I have a unique list of strings (the original idea was the column names in a table).
The task is to perform a maximal possible abbreviation of the list, so the list remains distinct.

For example `AAA, AB` can be abbreviated to `AA, AB`. (But not to `A, AB` – as `A` could be prefix of both `AAA` and `AB`).
`AAAA, BAAAA` can be shorten to `A, B`.
But `A1, A2` can’t be abbreviated at all.

Here are the sample data

```
create table tab as 
select 'AAA' col from dual union all
select 'AABA' col from dual union all
select 'COL1' col from dual union all
select 'COL21' col from dual union all
select 'AAAAAA' col from dual union all
select 'BBAA' col from dual union all
select 'BAAAA' col from dual union all
select 'AB' col from dual;
```

The expected result is

```
COL    ABR_COL                
------ ------------------------
AAA    AAA                      
AAAAAA AAAA                     
AABA   AAB                      
AB     AB                       
BAAAA  BA                       
BBAA   BB                       
COL1   COL1                     
COL21  COL2
```

I managed a brute force solution consisting of four subqueries, which I do not post on purpose, because I hope there exists a more simple solution from which I do not want to distract.

Btw there is a similar function in `r` called [`abbreviate`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/abbreviate.html), but I’m looking for SQL solution. Prefered `Oracle` solutions for other RDBMS are welcommed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the filtering in the recursive CTE:

```
with potential_abbreviations(col, abbr, lev) as (
      select col, col as abbr, 1 as lev
      from tab
      union all
      select pa.col, substr(pa.abbr, 1, length(pa.abbr) - 1) as abbr, lev + 1
      from potential_abbreviations pa
      where length(abbr) > 1 and
            not exists (select 1
                        from tab
                        where tab.col like substr(pa.abbr, 1, length(pa.abbr) - 1) || '%' and
                              tab.col <> pa.col
                       )
     )
select pa.col, pa.abbr
from (select pa.*, row_number() over (partition by pa.col order by pa.lev desc) as seqnum
      from potential_abbreviations pa
     ) pa
where seqnum = 1
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c7a5d649dce3a98e21c1bfdf97a3a93) is a db<>fiddle.

The `lev` is strictly not necessary.  You can use `length(abbr) desc` in the `order by`.  But, I usually include a recursion counter when I use recursive CTEs, so this is habit.

Doing the extra comparison in the CTE may look more complicated, but it simplifies the execution -- the recursion stops at the correct value.

This is also tested on unique single letter `col` values.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually possible using a recursive CTE. I don't really get it shorter than three subqueries (plus one query), but at least it is not constrained by string length. The steps are roughly as follows:

1. Calculate all potential abbreviations with a recursive CTE. This selects all column 
   names themselves and then the column names shortened by one letter, recursively:

Table:

```
 col    abbr
 --- -------
 AAA    AAA
 AAA    AA
 AAA    A
 ...
```

2. For each abbreviation, count how often it occurs

Table

```
ABBR    CONFLICT
----    --------
AA      3
AAA     2
AABA    1
...
```

3. Select the abbreviations that are the unique shortest ones, and also
   the abbreviations that are just the column name itself, and rank these by length of the abbreviation. In the example, you see that `AAA` conflicts with some other abbreviation but still must be chosen as it is equal to its unshortened name.

Table

```
COL     ABBR    CONFLICT    POS
-------------------------------
AAA     AAA     2           1
AAAAAA  AAAA    1           1
AAAAAA  AAAAA   1           2
AAAAAA  AAAAAA  1           3
AABA    AAB     1           1
...
```

4. Choose the first ranked abbreviation (or column name itself) for each column.

Table

```
COL     ABBR    POS
-------------------
AAA     AAA     1
AAAAAA  AAAA    1
AABA    AAB     1
...
```

#### Complete SQL

This results in the following SQL, with the above steps as CTEs:

```
with potential_abbreviations(col,abbr) as (
  select
      col
    , col as abbr
  from tab
  union all
  select
    col
  , substr(abbr, 1, length(abbr)-1 ) as abbr
  from potential_abbreviations
  where length(abbr) > 1
)
, abbreviation_counts as (
  select abbr
       , count(*) as conflict
  from potential_abbreviations
  group by abbr
)
, all_unique_abbreviations(col,abbr,conflict,pos) as (
select
    p.col
  , p.abbr
  , conflict
  , rank() over (partition by col order by p.abbr) as pos
  from potential_abbreviations p
    join abbreviation_counts c on p.abbr = c.abbr
    where conflict = 1 or p.col = p.abbr
)
select col, abbr, pos
from all_unique_abbreviations
where pos = 1
 order by col, abbr
```

#### Result

```
COL     ABBR
------- ----
AAA     AAA
AAAAAA  AAAA
AABA    AAB
AB      AB
AC1     AC
AD      AD
BAAAA   BA
BBAA    BB
COL1    COL1
COL21   COL2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c69b02/46)

Comment: Plus one for *recursive CTE*, this saves one subquery.

Comment: Please allow some time for others to try, as I stated I'm looking for the *simplest* possible solution.

Comment: Makes sense :) Maybe I can remove one more CTE :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a second approach, not added to the first answer as it is shorter and different. The steps are as follows:

1. Calculate all potential abbreviations for each name, recursively

SQL

```
  select
      col
    , col as abbr
  from tab
  union all
  select
    col
  , substr(abbr, 1, length(abbr)-1 ) as abbr
  from potential_abbreviations a
  where length(abbr) > 1
```

Results

```
 col    abbr
 --- -------
 AAA    AAA
 AAA    AA
 AAA    A
 ...
```

2. Then calculate the conflicts between abbreviations. Also keep track of the  column name that led to this abbreviation. We only want to keep abbreviations that cause no conflict, so the `min()` aggregate is of no concern.

SQL

```
select
    abbr
  , count(*) as conflicts
  , min(col) as best_candidate
  from potential_abbreviations
 group by abbr
having count(*) = 1
```

Result

```
ABBR    CONFLICTS BEST_CANDIDATE
------- --------- ---------------
AAAA    1         AAAAAA
AAAAA   1         AAAAAA
AAAAAA  1         AAAAAA
AAB     1         AABA
AABA    1         AABA
...
```

3. Finally, do a left join of the potential abbreviations with the best conflict-free candidates, and just use the column name if there was no conflict free resolution:

SQL

```
select
    p.col as col
  , nvl(min(c.abbr), p.col) as abbr
  from potential_abbreviations p
  left join conflict_free c on p.col = c.best_candidate
 where c.conflicts = 1 or p.abbr = p.col
 group by p.col
  order by col, abbr
```

#### Complete SQL

```
with potential_abbreviations(col,abbr) as (
  select
      col
    , col as abbr
  from tab
  union all
  select
    col
  , substr(abbr, 1, length(abbr)-1 ) as abbr
  from potential_abbreviations a
 where length(abbr) > 1
)
, conflict_free as (
    select
        abbr
      , count(*) as conflicts
      , min(col) as best_candidate
      from potential_abbreviations
     group by abbr
    having count(*) = 1
)
select
    p.col as col
  -- , c.best_candidate
  , nvl(min(c.abbr), p.col) as abbr
  -- , min(c.abbr) over (partition by c.best_candidate) shortest
  from potential_abbreviations p
  left join conflict_free c on p.col = c.best_candidate
 where c.conflicts = 1 or p.abbr = p.col
 group by p.col, c.best_candidate
 order by col, abbr
```

#### Result

```
COL     ABBR
------- ----
AAA     AAA
AAAAAA  AAAA
AABA    AAB
AB      AB
AC1     AC
AD      AD
BAAAA   BA
BBAA    BB
COL1    COL1
COL21   COL2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c69b02/188)

Note: For Postgresql, the recursive CTE must be `with recursive` while Oracle does not like the word `recursive` at all there.